# GitLab runner only executing one command

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
- build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install -g gulp
    - npm install
    - gulp
```

But the runner is only executing the first command (`npm install -g gulp`). It runs the first command and reports success, without executing the others.

The build log:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.6.1 (c52ad4f)
Using Shell executor...
Running on WINBUILDER...

Fetching changes...

HEAD is now at 2df18c5 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From https://.../client
   2df18c5..b4efae8  master     -> origin/master
Checking out b4efae85 as master...

$ npm install -g gulp

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- gulp@3.9.1 

Build succeeded
```

I've seen several config examples using multiple commands in a stage. I don't understand why the other commands are not running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually an NPM bug as described here:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2938

NPM closes the shell upon exit and subsequent commands are not called.

A workaround is described in the issue above. Just add a `call` command before calling NPM:

```
stages:
- build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - call npm install -g gulp
    - call npm install
    - gulp
```